# SQLite query with ORDER BY limited

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

```
date       |  id
-----------|------
unixtime_1 |  2
unixtime_1 |  7
unixtime_1 |  9
unixtime_1 |  24
unixtime_1 |  29
unixtime_1 |  21
unixtime_2 |  8
```

So far I get the results from such a table doing so:

```
SELECT date, id FROM table ORDER BY date DESC, id ASC
```

and I get

```
unixtime_1 |  2
unixtime_1 |  7
unixtime_1 |  9
unixtime_1 |  21
unixtime_1 |  24
unixtime_1 |  29
unixtime_2 |  8
```

I was wondering whether I could `LIMIT` the result so that in the range `id=1-10` `id=11-20` and `id=21-30` I could get in the result only the record with the higher id.
So:

```
unixtime_1 |  9
unixtime_1 |  29
```

Since for id `range=11-20` there isn't any record, it should be skip the range.
*The range now are 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 but are custom ranges* set by me according to the user request *so I should be able to change them*.

Is that possible via query?

Thank you

Comment: No, id is not continuous. It's an ID a give to the record according to the selection of the user

Comment: This looks brutal to me, because SQLite does not have analytic functions.  But I have upvoted your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you have any other suggestion to do so in Android development context? I would like to avoid working programmatically since it would be too much complex code to maintain...

Comment: What happened to the `unixtime_2` record?  Is its absence in the result set just a typo, or is there a reason why it is missing?

Comment: I just deleted unixtime_2 to make the explanation more clear, but there could be unixtime_2, unixtime_3 unixtime_n

Comment: You didn't delete it, but that's OK provided that the logic doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest requirement should be possible to achieve merely by grouping by the date and `(id - 1) / <some_number>`, where in your example `<some_number>` would be 10.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date, (id - 1) / 10 AS id_grp, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY date, (id - 1) / 10
) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.id = t2.max_id
ORDER BY
    t1.date, t1.id;
```

You may choose any range you want `1 - num` by simply replacing 10 in my query with the end of the range.

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible, in the meanwhile I was attempting to read the query and maybe I got the logic BUT this is not suitable for me as I would need to set each range as the problem is not exactly as I wrote in the first post but much more complicated and I need to be able to set ranges

Comment: @Soul Then maybe you didn't ask the right question.  I can only answer what I can see.

Comment: I edited the first post, now I hope the request is more clear than before. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand correctly and if your range is id=1-3

you could simply do:

```
SELECT id, date FROM table WHERE id>=1 AND id<=3 ORDER by id DESC, date DESC limit 1;
```

this will give you only 1 record with the highest id in the range id=1-3.

you can store it and perform another query for another range and combine them later

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> SELECT date, MAX(ID) FROM table GROUP BY date

Comment: In this way I cannot set the range, I need a precise output to give to the app in order to be processed.